# top level `continue` in nested loop C instead of current level loop

Tags: c, nested-loops

How do I make `continue` goes to the top level of loop? I mean like this:

```
for(;;){ // top level loop
   statement1;
   for(;;){ // second level loop
      statement2;
      if (condition1){
         continue; // I expect it continue to the start of top level so it will execute statement1.
      }
   }
   statement3;
}
```

This is my real case why I got problem above, basically my program is sending data with UDP socket which the data should be sent fast. I know UDP is unrealiable but it's okay the data is tolerated with loss too.

```
 for (;;) {  // Streaming data...
    camera_fb_t* fb = esp_camera_fb_get();
    size_t quotient = fb ->len / UDP_BUF_SIZE;
    size_t remainder = fb ->len % UDP_BUF_SIZE;
    unsigned int i = 0;
    for (; i < quotient; i++) {  // sending packet by packet.
      if (uwc_udp_send_raw((const void*)(fb ->buf + (i * UDP_BUF_SIZE)),
                           UDP_BUF_SIZE) < 0) {
        ESP_LOGE(uwc_tag_event, "Error in iteration: %i", i);
        uwc_udp_send_raw("ERR",3); // Tell receiver there was corrupt during send data.
        esp_camera_fb_return(fb);
        continue; // I expect it continue to the top level
      }
    }
    if (remainder) {  // last packet to be sent if remainder exist
      uwc_udp_send_raw((const void*)(fb ->buf + (i * UDP_BUF_SIZE)),
                       remainder);
      ESP_LOGE(uwc_tag_event, "Error in last iteration!");
    }
    esp_camera_fb_return(fb);
  }
```

Comment: use `break` instead

Comment: But it will execute ```statement3``` which i don't want it.

Comment: You need to use some boolean state that you check after the inner loop (before `statement3;`). Unfortunately there's really no way around it.

Comment: guard it with 
      `if (condition1) statement3`

Comment: Re-arrange your code to be less messy, to be honest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a `flag` or `continue` or `goto`:

```
for (;;) {
    camera_fb_t *uwcCamFb = esp_camera_fb_get();
    unsigned char *from = uwcCamFb->buf;
    size_t toSend = uwcCamFb->len;

    for( int i = 0; toSend > 0; i++ ) {
        size_t sendSize = toSend > UDP_BUF_SIZE ? UDP_BUF_SIZE : toSend;
        if( uwc_udp_send_raw( from, sendSize ) < 0) {
            ESP_LOGE( uwc_tag_event, "Error in iteration: %i", i );
            uwc_udp_send_raw( "ERR", 3 );
            break;
        }
        toSend -= sendSize;
        from += sendSize;
    }
    // Update...
    // Removed conditional as it reflected flawed OP logic...
    // if( toSend == 0 )
        esp_camera_fb_return( uwcCamFb );
}
```

If you need/want to distinguish the LAST packet, add `if( toSend < UDP_BUF_SIZE )` to log that particular error message instead...

It seems your OP used both `fb` and `uwcCamFb`... I can only guess this corrects that apparently mistake...

(Thank you to @Persixty for a bug report that has been fixed.)

Comment: @Persixty Thank you for pointing that out... Fixed... Making the revisions, I presumed there was an alloc'd buffer to be free'd, and didn't go back to the OP to check the problem. Thank you for your sharp eyes... :-)

Comment: Sorry If I made you confused, `uwcCamFb` was same as `fb` the difference was `uwcCamFb` is global variable which it's bad isn't it? So I think let's forget `uwcCamFb` I have updated my question.

Comment: @CitraDewi Something didn't make sense. Since your change uses only the local variable, my version still corresponds... Just odd that the `return()` is skipped if there's been an error... But, if that's what you want to happen...

Comment: I have idea, why don't we keep try send the failed packet if we know that packet is failed to send, notice where you put `break`  word. So the condition part should be change to the `while` from `if`. That send error is happened in sender side actually, not receiver side so it should keep send until finish then there's no any error message anymore or there's no any break statement.

Comment: I want edit your answer but suggested edit queue is full.

Comment: Btw thanks for this answer, I got your idea, I was using remainder and quotient method  to sending known current size remaining data before it, which it was slower than this method I think?

Comment: @CitraDewi Re: "keep trying to send"... That's up to you. How many retries?? Re: "Edit queue"... I think you need a higher 'reputation' to do that... Re: "Slower"... This version only calls 'send()' in one location. Less code (that works) is always better than extra special-case  "mop-up" code to handle remaining loose bits...

Comment: @Fe2O3 I think 10 times retries enough. If 10 times retries exceeded then put current frame buffer so it will be reused by framework which I don't know too what it does but just return current framebuffer after used it with `esp_camera_fb_return(fb)` and go back to the top level of loop with continue?

Comment: Pretty sure that Persixty was wrong and your original code was right. The call to `esp_camera_fb_get` is likely to either allocate or lock the buffer that it returns. So you always need to call `esp_camera_fb_return` to either free or unlock that buffer. Note that OP's code always calls `esp_camera_fb_return`, regardless of whether there's a send error or not.

Comment: @user3386109 Persixty was right wrt the OP problem statement. The OP wanted to bypass the `return()` if an error occurred. (strange). However, I agree with you that `get()` and `return()` probably function like `fopen()/fclose()`... Without the doco, it's tough to say...

Comment: Persixty was wrong because he never got past the first code snippet to look at the actual code. In the actual code, the `fb_return()` is both inside the loop, and after the loop. It's never skipped.

Comment: @user3386109 Notice the 'editted' label on the OP... What you are seeing now is not the OOP... (Original original post...)...

Comment: I'm aware of the timeline. The timeline icon is under the downvote button next to the question. Click on `toggle format` in the `when` column to see the actual times. Version2 of the question, which contained the OP's code was posted at 19:56:59. Version3 which contained both `esp_camera_fb_return()` calls was posted 4 minutes later. So version3 was up 25 minutes before Persixty posted their answer, and an hour and 10 minutes before this answer. Version 1 of this answer handled `fb_return()` correctly, and it was wrong of Persixty to convince you to change it. I urge you to revert that change.

Comment: @user3386109 It's tough when the ground shifts... Because pairing `get()/return()` just makes sense (see previous comments about 'strange') I have modified the source in this response... Yes, it "feels better" now...

Comment: Agreed that it's tough when the ground shifts. I've been cheering for this answer all along. It *is* the right answer since it addresses the true problem that the OP was having, and not just the [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) that was presented in version 1.

Answer (score 6):

This is a rare case where you may use a `goto`. * Ducks for cover expecting flame-war and down votes *

People will get excited and declare your code automatically unreadable by a single use of `goto` and generally wring their hands.
But in these very rare cases the cleanest and most readable code has a `goto`. There are exceptions to almost every rule!

Remember, there is almost always a better way than using `goto` but the real issue with it is that liberal use quickly creates 'spaghetti' code.
But a single use can be justified.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo(){
    for(int i=0;i<10;++i){
        for(int j=0;j<10;++j){
            if(j==i*i){
                goto OUTER_LOOP;
            }
        }
        printf("%d\n",i);
OUTER_LOOP: continue;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

People will claim you should set a boolean and break and insist that is 'more readable'. It's no more readable at all.
There are few dogmatic laws in programming but "goto is always an necessarily bad" is one of them. It's almost true. But not quite entirely true.

Java has a labelled break statement almost specifically to provide a way of avoiding this use-case for `goto` and doesn't have `goto` itself because it has a fix.

I think it's arguable that there is a tiny gap in the language. But in practice this situation is actually quite rare.

Comment: I'd actually upvote this. Gotos are what the assembly understands directly, so we shouldn't be prejudiced against them on principle.

Comment: Yeah, honestly although programs of old might have had terrible messes of gotos, you barely ever see them anymore so the confusion that arises from having a lot of them isn't really a problem. I wish people redirected half their hatred of goto to a few other practices that are altogether useless, ugly, and potentially result in confusion.

Answer (score 2):

I think goto can solve this problem, I would not use it in normal situation but this is acceptable I think, define a label in the top level for and use goto label in the inner one :]

It's up to you if you want a boolean and check it in every inner loop or use a goto though.

Edit: Honestly 2 for loop are not much, maybe a simple if condition is enough

Comment: ony if top level does not check value of the control variable

Comment: I wouldn't recommend putting the label at the top. I doubt the OP is really running two nested infinite loops. To make sure the "increment" step happens correctly, like in a regular continue statement, the label should be at the end.

Comment: @0___________ could you elaborate?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica yes you are right, I meant top level for not on top of the for sorry for the misunderstanding:')

Comment: No worries. Just means the answer may benefit from a demonstration ;-)

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica *cries in mobile user*

Comment: @IvanLoGreco https://godbolt.org/z/o6PT17Mo8

Comment: Hero upvote for daring to mention the g-word.

Comment: Agreed. gotos are generally a poor practice, but they exist because some things are actually simpler with them.

Answer (score 0):

You need flags:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 15; i ++)
    {
        int execST3 = 1;
        printf("ST1 i = %d\n", i);

        for(int j = 0; j < 15; j ++)
        {
            printf("ST2 j = %d\n", j);
            if(j == 3) {execST3 = 0; break;}
        }
        if(execST3)printf("ST3\n");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code can be made to work cleanly by replacing the inner infinite loop with a goto style infinite loop.  From the compiler point of view that eliminates the second for loop, so that the continue, continues at the first infinite loop.

```
for (;;)
{
   statement1;
   INNER_LOOP:;
   {
      statement2;
      if (condition1)
      {
         continue; // at the top of the first loop.
      }
      goto INNER_LOOP;
   }
   statement3;
}
```